# Cannot convert HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf or pdfkit

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm trying to convert a large HTML to PDF. So far I tried two approaches with the same no desired result.

I execute this on the terminal:

```
wkhtmltopdf my_html_file.html my_pdf_file.pdf
```

On the other hand, I tried the conversion inside a Python script:

```
import pdfkit

with open('my_html_file.html') as f:
    pdfkit.from_file(f, 'my_pdf_file.pdf')
```

In both cases the output file generated (my_pdf_file.pdf) only has 1 page and does not contain all the content from the HTML file.

Comment: How was your HTML generated? Is it from an external source? The file could have broken HTML, which is causing the PDF generation to fail silently

Comment: Ah, very helpful comment. It is generated using Python. Do you know how I can check if the file is broken?

Comment: Try opening the html on chrome browser. Do all the pages show?